# Importing Ghostscript in Python on Windows 8

Tags: python, ghostscript

I've been trying to import ghostscript into Python in order to convert pdf files to a .tiff format.

I am using Python version 2.7.10 on Windows 8.

I have successfully downloaded and installed ghostscript using pip, and it appears in the correct location (...\Anaconda\Lib\sitepackages). I've confirmed that other packages located in this directory can be imported into Python.

I am using the command `import ghostscript`

When I do so, I get an error message:

> RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript DLL in registry

The traceback indicates that calling the file "ghoscript_init_.py" successfully imports _gsprint as gs.

However, when the import function attempts to access "ghostscript_gsprint.py", it produces the RuntimeError where it is unable to find the Ghostscript DLL.

I would be very grateful for any advice or tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Jamie's answer is not very helpful, OP is saying that he has indeed downloaded and installed ghostscript and even posted that he's using a python 2.7 which is supposed to be supported by ghostscript no problem.

I got the same error:
`RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript DLL in registry`

My problem was actually that I had Python(3.6) 64bit installed while having Ghostscript 32bit installed. Uninstalling the 32bit Ghostscript and installing 64bit Ghostscript resolved the issue.

You can check your python version by running python.exe and checking the header message.

> python
>
> Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC
>   v.1900 **64 bit** (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Yep this worked for me.  Thanks.  For those of you getting the error OSError: Ghostscript is not installed from Camelot.  You can install it using the instructions here. This is likely the fix.  I still installed via the ghostscript installer, and not pip.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

As well as installing `ghostscript` python bindings from PyPI with `pip install ghostscript`, you also need to install the correct Ghostscript program for your platform, as described on the [PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghostscript). That page states that version 8.x is required, but I'm currently using 9.2 successfully.

The download links are [here](http://ghostscript.com/download/).