# Importing Ghostscript on Windows 10

Tags: python, ghostscript, python-3.8

I am trying to import `ghostscript` into Python

when I type `import ghostscript`, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in
>
> import ghostscript   File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\ghostscript_*init*_.py",
> line 35, in 
> from . import _gsprint as gs   File "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\ghostscript_gsprint.py",
> line 505, in 
> raise RuntimeError('Can not find Ghostscript DLL in registry') RuntimeError: Can not find Ghostscript DLL in registry

I am using Windows 10.

I have confirmed I am using Python 3.8.3, 32-bit.

I found this thread: [Importing Ghostscript in Python on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886385/importing-ghostscript-in-python-on-windows-8), but it was not very helpful.

Any suggestions?

I'm not sure how to figure out if I'm using ghostscript version 32-bit or 64-bit.

**Edit #1:**

I installed Ghostscript by doing `python -m pip install ghostscript`

Comment: Surely you did download and install the actual Ghostscript program, right? https://www.ghostscript.com/download.html If not then no wonder.

Comment: Edited my post, I can't just use the pip command?

Comment: Yes, but you also need to install Ghostscript for Windows. You can download it here: https://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

Comment: @LunchBox according to the [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/), the prerequisite installations are Python 2.7 or higher, setuptools, and Ghostscript.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/), the `ghostscript` PyPi package requires an existing installation of Ghostscript:

> python-ghostscript requires
>
> - Python 2.7 or higher (tested with Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.6 and 3.6)
> - setuptools for installation (see below)
> - Ghostscript Version 8.x or higher (tested with 9.x)

You can download Ghostscript for Windows from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/) or [ghostscript.com](https://ghostscript.com/releases/gpdldnld.html).